# Visual Studio 2017 crash on startup Show some dependent package error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When I am trying to launch VS 2017, is throwing some missing package error stating "Something went wrong".

Error Log:

> [2544:0006][2018-06-01T11:21:08] Error 0x80131500: The dependent
>   package of
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Enterprise,version=15.7.27703.2018'
>   cannot be found:
>   Component.Redgate.SQLPrompt.VsPackage,version=9.1.12.5083.    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Dependencies.DependencyManager.FindDependentPackages(Dependency
>   dependency, DependencyComparer comparer, Dictionary`2 packageIndex,
>   IPackage holder)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Dependencies.DependencyManager.BuildGraphRecursive(IPackage
>   graphRoot, DependencyNode node, DependencyComparer comparer,
>   Dictionary`2 packageIndex, Dictionary`2 nodeIndex, Boolean splitNodes)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Dependencies.DependencyManager.BuildGraphCore(IPackage
>   root, IEnumerable`1 packages, DependencyComparer comparer,
>   Dictionary`2 packageIndex, Dictionary`2 nodeIndex, Boolean splitNodes,
>   DependencyCollection deprecated)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Dependencies.DependencyManager.BuildGraph(IPackage
>   root, IEnumerable`1 packages, Boolean isUpdate,
>   IDependencyComparisonSeed seed, DependencyCollection deprecated)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.GetDependencyGraph(Product
>   product)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.TryBuildDependencyGraph(Product
>   product, Exception& error, Boolean overwrite, ITelemetryOperation
>   telemetryOperation) [2544:0006][2018-06-01T11:21:08] Error 0x80131500:
>   The dependent package of
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Enterprise,version=15.7.27703.2018'
>   cannot be found:
>   Component.Redgate.SQLPrompt.VsPackage,version=9.1.12.5083.    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.CreateInstallOperation(Product
>   product, String destination, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation
>   telemetryOperation)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Repair(CancellationToken token)

Answer (score 1):

T wasn't able to launch or Repair but after a long and exhausted research, I silly thing worked for me.

I choose to modify option and then again modify to repair selected packages. Once Done everything looks good.